# Meteor method call with useTracker and render html

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, use-state

Meteor newbie here, I want to do a meteor call to a meteor method which does a get request to an 3rd party API and forwards the returned JSON response to my initial meteor call.

I want to use the returned JSON response to render my html code

here is my js file with meteor method

```
Meteor.methods({
  'jira.get'(projectName, maxResult) {
    if (!this.userId) {
      throw new Meteor.Error('Not authorized.');
    }
    check(projectName, String);
    check(maxResult, String);
    const base64Auth = Meteor.users.findOne({ _id: this.userId }).Authorization;

    const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      url: `https://myCompany.com/.../search?jql=project=${projectName}&maxResults=${maxResult}`,
      headers: {
        Authorization: base64Auth,
      },
    };

    const future = new Future();

    request(options, function(error, response) {
      if (error) throw new Error(error);
      const jiraResponse = JSON.parse(response.body);
      future.return(jiraResponse);
    });

    return future.wait();
  },
});
```

and my JSX file that calls above Meteor method is as below

```
export const App = () => {
   
    Meteor.call('jira.get', project='test', maxResult = '10', (error, jiraResponse) => {
      console.log("this is working fine: "jiraResponse)
    });

    console.log('this is undefined', jiraResponse)
}
```

If i use useState as below, initially the last console log `console.log(jiraResp)` prints `{}` as expected but it goes into infinite loop with the correct data after that

```
 const [ jiraResp, setjiraResp ] = useState({})
  Meteor.call('jira.get', project='test', maxResult = '10', (error, jiraResponse) => {
    if (jiraResponse){
      console.log("got the resp ")
      setjiraResp(jiraResponse);
    }
    else{
      console.log("not recieved")
    }
  });
  console.log(jiraResp)
```

How do i get the response of meteor call and update my jiraResponse just once ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `jiraResp` in the method callback will trigger a re-render and since you are making the method call in the render method itself, it will repeat the call, hence the loop.

You need to use `useEffect`:

```js
const [ jiraResp, setjiraResp ] = useState({});
useEffect(() =>
  Meteor.call('jira.get', project = 'test', maxResult = '10', (error, jiraResponse) => {
    if (jiraResponse) {
      console.log("got the resp ");
      setjiraResp(jiraResponse);
    } else {
      console.log("not recieved");
    }
  }), []);
console.log(jiraResp);
```